# How do I select a specific user?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin

I am making a PHP website where users can login. I want "normal" users to redirect to the home page. But when the Admin user logs in want to redirect somewhere else. I tried this but it won't work. Anyone knows how to do this?

```
$adminLogin = (mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `userswebsite` WHERE `username` = 'Admin'"));
        
        if ($adminLogin == '13')
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
            header('Location:informatie.php');  //Redirect gebruiker naar "informatie"
            exit();
        }
        
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
            header('Location:index.php');   //Redirect gebruiker naar "thuis"
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: maybe you could explain the current problem? What happens, if user login? What happens, if admin login? There must be a mysql_result() on your executed query.

Comment: When a user logs in they should be redirected to index.php. But when admin logs in he should be redirected to information.php. But I can't figure out how to determine if the user is admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

After mysql_query you have to do the mysql_fetch_array for getting the record from database

```
   $adminLogin = (mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `userswebsite` WHERE `username` = 'Admin'"));

   $user_id = mysql_fetch_array($adminLogin);       

    if ($user_id == 13)
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
        header('Location:informatie.php');  //Redirect gebruiker naar "informatie"
        exit();
    }

    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
        header('Location:index.php');   //Redirect gebruiker naar "thuis"
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but still redirects to informatie.php :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are a beginner in php

Ok, you should do this

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `userswebsite` WHERE `username` = 'Admin'");
if ($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
  $adminlogin = $row['user_id'];
}

    if (isset($adminLogin) && $adminLogin == '13')
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
        header('Location:informatie.php');  //Redirect gebruiker naar "informatie"
        exit();
    }

    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
        header('Location:index.php');   //Redirect gebruiker naar "thuis"
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but still redirects to informatie.php.

Comment: whats the result of `var_dump($adminLogin)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, as your website grows you may need help with managing it. It would be much better to add a new field called "usergroup". Then you could select * from userswebsite WHERE usergroup = "admin" or "moderator". That way if you need a little help, you don't have to give them your admin password.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a group column in your user table, that way you can have multiple user access levels, plus I think it'd would make it far easier to do what you're trying to do.

```
define('SITE_NORMAL',0);
define('SITE_ADMIN',1);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `group_id` FROM `userswebsite` WHERE `username` = 'Admin' AND passwordhash='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$login = $row['user_id'];
$groupid = row['group_id'];

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  //zet gebruiker sessie
$_SESSION['group_id'] = $groupid;

header( 'Location:'.($groupid==SITE_ADMIN ? 'informatie.php':'index.php') );
exit();
```

This way any user can be made an administrator, just set the group_id to 1.

Of course, you should be moving on to MySQLi or PDO since PHP's mysql has been deprecated.

Also make sure you're checking for a valid login on every page. Don't assume the $_SESSION information is valid.